# Flask - "ValueError: Detected newline in header value. This is a potential security prob lem"

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to python and am playing around with flask and have built a copy of what's taught on one of the udacity courses where you can upload ASCII art to a pretty basic web page.

After playing around I noticed that I'm getting an error when I upload ASCII art that says:

***ValueError: Detected newline in header value.  This is a potential security problem***

I have no clue what the issue is, I've attached both the code and request headers below:

Headers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vMP0.jpg

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, flash, request
from datetime import datetime
import sqlite3
import os
from os.path import expanduser
app = Flask(__name__)


def fetch(name):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('art.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * from {} ORDER BY created DESC".format(name))
    return cursor

def insert(title, art):
    time = datetime.now()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('art.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO art VALUES (?,?,?)""",(title, art,time))
    conn.commit()

def delete(title):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('art.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""DELETE FROM art WHERE title = '{}'""".format(title))
    conn.commit()


def render_front(title='', art='', error='', posts=''):
    return render_template('front.html',title=title, art=art, error=error, posts=posts)

def get_posts(table):
    x = fetch(table)
    posts = [i for i in x]
    return posts

@app.route('/post/<title>/<art>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def new_post(title=None,art=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form.getlist('hidden'):
            title = request.form['hidden']
            delete(title)
            posts = get_posts('art')
            return render_front(posts=posts)
        elif request.form.getlist('titles'):
            title = request.form['titles']
            art = request.form['arts']
            if title and art:
                insert(str(title), str(art))
                return redirect('/post/{}/{}'.format(title,art))
            else:
                error = 'ERROR SOMEWHERE'
                return render_front(error=error, art=art, title=title)
    else:
        posts = [[title,art]]
        return render_front(posts=posts)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form.getlist('hidden'):
            title = request.form['hidden']
            delete(title)
            posts = get_posts('art')
            return render_front(posts=posts)
        elif request.form.getlist('titles'):
            title = request.form['titles']
            art = request.form['arts']
            if title and art:
                insert(str(title), str(art))
                return redirect('/post/{}/{}'.format(title,art))
            else:
                error = 'ERROR SOMEWHERE'
                return render_front(error=error, art=art, title=title)
    else:
        posts = get_posts('art')
        return render_front(posts=posts)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Comment: Which version of python and flask is this running under?

Comment: Flask: 0.10.1; Python: 2.7.6

Answer (score 1):

If your values in Header contains symbols newline \n or \r, then will be raise ValueError with text error: "Detected newline in header value.  This is a potential security problem". This can occur, if you use redirect and header has key Location with target url and target url contains symbols newline \n or \r